# Is it ok to handle specific exception like this

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I have seen such code in many places, is there any benefit of this..Or this is a wrong practice..

```
try
{
    ......
}   
catch (NullReferenceException ex)
{
    Data.LogError(ex, "Exception occourred while ...");
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    Data.LogError(ex, "Exception occourred while ...");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Data.LogError(ex, "Exception occourred while ...");
}
```

In context of **specific exception handling.**

Comment: If the code inside each catch is different, yeah that's valid.

Comment: It's normally wrong. Catching a NullReferenceException of an IndexOutOfRange exception like that is very iffy.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I would agree however it is perfectly acceptable depending on requirements

Comment: @MatthewWatson .. The code I have seen was simply logging the exception..Does the order of specific expection handled makes any difference??

Comment: @James yes the order is important the most specific exception should be handled first. To clarify if you put the catch(Exception ex) above the other 2 catch statements then they would never ever be reached.

Comment: @James It's not simply logging the exception. It's logging the exception *and absorbing it*. So nothing else will see the exception.

Comment: Thats the way we handled all errors on http://madhues.com

Comment: @SunnyRGupta You just logged `NullReferenceExeption` and let the program continue? Gosh! And `StackOverflowException` and `OutOfMemoryException` too?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I catch them, log them and then kill the process. Once a week I sit and analyse the logs. (Its just a small service I use on that site, does not impact the business logic.)

Comment: @SunnyRGupta Ok, but that's not what the code in question is doing. The code above is logging the exceptions but then *not* doing anything else - it's not propagating them or killing the process. I assumed when you said "Thats the way we handled all errors" that you meant you did the same as the code in the OP does - but it seems you don't after all.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I wish there were a nice means of taking action in response to an exception without `catch`ing it.  While there are cases where code may expect to resolve an exception and discover that it can't (and must thus rethrow), I suspect there are at least as many cases where code should take action in response to exceptions it can't possibly resolve (e.g. consider the sequence 
acquire lock; break guarded-object invariants, fix invariants; release lock). If an unexpected exception occurs, the guarded object should be *expressly invalidated* even though such invalidation won't...

Comment: ...resolve the exception. Another problem situation is a constructor which throws an exception after acquiring a resource on behalf of the object under construction; such resource must be released, even though (actually, *because*) the code handling the exception can't resolve it and allow execution to proceed normally. To my mind, using `catch` when taking action which can't possibly resolve the exception is icky, especially given the popular mantra "only catch exceptions one can handle".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is benefit if you are going to handle the exceptions differently in the catch block (i.e. perform different actions as a result of the exception being thrown).

Otherwise you could remove the more specific exception handlers and just use the most generic:

```
catch(Exception ex)
```

Note: If the exception is being used purely for logging then sometimes it can be useful to re-throw the exception to bubble it up to the rest of the application:

```
try{

}
catch(Exception ex){
   // Log exception here
   throw;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is even better than a generic `catch`, because you can choose what to do with a certain type of exception. Say, you want to show a message if a file doesn't exist, and offer to retry, but kill the application otherwise.

You can also handle exceptions differently, because they offer different properties (thanks to Rots for pointing that out):

```
try
{
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.FileName + " not found");
    //Retry
}
catch(Exception ex) // Exception does not contain ex.FileName
{
    //Save stuff
    //Exit
}
```

Only the first matching block will be executed.

Comment: I seem to remember that other types of Exceptions offer further properties than a generic exception, potentially providing more information if it was caught. EG: IOException could potentially contain a FilePath property.

Answer (score 0):

The given approach is best in case if you wanted to handle/log any specific exception in it's own way. Also, ideal in scenario, where you can inform user with more apt details than giving generic messages. Now, if you don't want to handle different exceptions then you can goahead with one catch block, which catch all exception.